# How to get the top 5 elements from different columns with a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Problem

I have the following table in a PostgreSQL 9.6 DB:

```
 factorA | factorB | factorC | result 
---------+---------+---------+-------
       1 |      5  |     100 |     1
       1 |      6  |     200 |     3
       2 |      6  |      60 |     6
       2 |      5  |      70 |    10
```

The table is of course much larger with many more factors that follow.

Now I have two questions:

1. How much did the top 5 factorA-values contribute to result
2. How much did the top 5 factorB-value contribute to result

(The factorC value is only there to show that there are other columns which however are not of interest for this question)

To answer question 1 we see that `sum(value)` is 20 and `sum(value where factorA = 1)` is 4 and `sum(value where factorA = 2)` is 16. So we can calculate the factorA=1 contributed 4/20=20% and factorB=2 contributed 16/20=80%. The same principle applies to factorB. So the desired result is something I can read those values from:

```json
{"factorA": {1: 0.2, 2: 0.8, ...}, "factorB": {5: 0.55, 6: 0.45, ...}}
```

Answering each of those two questions individually in SQL is no problem:

```sql
select * from (
    select
        factorA,
        row_number() over (partition by 't' order by sum(result) desc) rank,
        sum(result) / sum(sum(result)) over (partition by 't') contribution
    from (values(1,5,100,1), (1,6,200,3), (2,6,60,6), (2,5,70,10)) x(factorA, factorB, factorC, result)
    group by factorA
) x where rank <= 5
```

This results in:

```
 factorA | rank |      contribution
---------+------+-----------------------
       2 |    1 | 0.80000000000000000000
       1 |    2 | 0.20000000000000000000
```

Replacing all "factorA" with "factorB" will answer the second question. However the problem is that in reality the table does not only contain 4 values, but actually hundred thousands of values, but not very many factors. So to run the query a full table scan is almost inevitable. Thus the query will be slow. Running it twice, once for factorA and once for factorB causes two table scans. I would like to avoid that and answer both questions with a single query.

## What I have tried

My best try so far is this:

```sql
select *
from
(
    select
        x.*,
        dense_rank() over (order by contributionA desc) rankA,
        dense_rank() over (order by contributionB desc) rankB
    from (
        select
            factorA,
            factorB,
            sum(sum(result)) over (partition by factorA) / sum(sum(result)) over (partition by 't')::float contributionA,
            sum(sum(result)) over (partition by factorB) / sum(sum(result)) over (partition by 't')::float contributionB
        from (values(1,5,100,1), (1,6,200,3), (2,6,60,6), (2,5,70,10)) x(factorA, factorB, factorC, result)
        group by factorA, factorB
    ) x
) x
where rankA <= 5 and rankB <= 5
```

This results in:

```
 factora | factorb | contributiona | contributionb | ranka | rankb
---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------
       2 |       5 |           0.8 |          0.55 |     1 |     1
       1 |       5 |           0.2 |          0.55 |     2 |     1
       2 |       6 |           0.8 |          0.45 |     1 |     2
       1 |       6 |           0.2 |          0.45 |     2 |     2
```

And that is a reasonable result except that the filtering for "top 5" is broken, because if two contributions are actually identical, then they share the same rank and thus the result will have 6 or more results. As a demonstration here is the query with only the "top 1", but it still gives the top 2:

```sql
select *
from
(
    select
        x.*,
        dense_rank() over (order by contributionA desc) rankA,
        dense_rank() over (order by contributionB desc) rankB
    from (
        select
            factorA,
            factorB,
            sum(sum(result)) over (partition by factorA) / sum(sum(result)) over (partition by 't')::float contributionA,
            sum(sum(result)) over (partition by factorB) / sum(sum(result)) over (partition by 't')::float contributionB
        from (values(1,5,100,1), (1,6,200,1), (2,6,60,1), (2,5,70,1)) x(factorA, factorB, factorC, result)
        group by factorA, factorB
    ) x
) x
where rankA <= 1 and rankB <= 1
```

Comment: Is intermediate table with top rankA plus top rankB rows an option?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to aggregate *after* calculating the ranks, not before:

```
select sum(case when rankA <= 5 then cumeFactorA end) / sum(result::float),
       sum(case when rankB <= 5 then cumeFactorB end) / sum(result::float)      
from (select x.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by factorA desc) as rankA,
             dense_rank() over (order by factorB desc) as rankB,
             sum(result) over (order by factorA) as cumeFactorA,
             sum(result) over (order by factorB) as cumeFactorB,
             sum(result) over () as total_result
      from (values(1,5,100,1), (1,6,200,1), (2,6,60,1), (2,5,70,1)) x(factorA, factorB, factorC, result)
    ) x
where rankA <= 5 or rankB <= 5;
```

Comment: The query gives me the values (3,3) rather than the expected (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5). For the dataset in the first example it gives me (2.4, 3.1) rather than the expected (0.8, 0.2, 0.45, 0.55).